# Перевод причины закрытия вопроса

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, локализация

Всем привет! Вопрос касательно локализации блока, описывающего причину закрытия вопроса.

Сейчас увидел закрытый вопрос с пометкой: "закрыт по причине того, что не по теме". Звучит как-то неестественно, разве нет?

Не знаю как сейчас выглядят остальные причины закрытия, но подозреваю, что так же нелепо. Может стоит вообще переделать структуру этого блока, например на: "Закрыто. Причина: ххх" и так далее? Это больше будет подходить для русской локализации.

Comment: Зачем же подозревать? Поизучайте. )

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите конкретный пример.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky любой вопрос, закрытый не по теме.

https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5&oq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5&aqs=chrome..69i57.319j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Конкретный пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443987/